# Can anyone explain the behavior of alt-enter in intellij when trying to import an unresolved symbol?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am currently in the process of porting a fairly sizable java project to scala so unsurprisingly I am hitting a lot of unresolved symbols. I am using intellij and it has a useful tool to help you find imports, you click on the unresolved symbol, and then hit alt-enter. This is great, but in my experience it is extremely unreliable in how it operates.

Sometimes it looks like this and you can simply hit enter (maybe after some down) and it imports what you want:

[image: Sometimes it looks like this]

But other times it looks like this and you have to go down to the Import class option before you see the menu from the previous picture:

[image: or this]

And when you get this version depending on what you are doing it on the options and order may be very different. I just wish I had a consistent understanding of why the IDE does one thing some times and another thing other times... any insights into behaviors or settings I could change to get intellij to operate in a comprehensible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second screen shows a standard popup with available [Intention actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). It is recomputed every time you invoke `Alt + Enter`.

Chooser on the first screen is provided by the [Auto Import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html) popup, you may turn it off in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Java | Show import popup for classes` (it really should be in Scala section though). It tries to find applicable classes for unresolved references in background, and explicitly ask you if you want to import something.

[image]

It is much more discoverable and often is more convenient. For example it allows you to paste a snippet of code and add all relevant imports without moving caret at all. This popup may be cancelled, but should reappear after any keystroke.

Comment: Cool, thanks maybe I can set them to different shortcuts so it doesn't feel totally random which one I get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to tell you except that sometimes IntelliJ understands you want to import a given class and sometimes it offers you to create the-said object.

In this case, without any context, I'd offer you to either create an object/class `ListBuffer` (because who said you *want* to import one, at this point?) or import one (which one is what IntelliJ offers in screen n°1) or a value/variable that still need to be defined somewhere or a parameterless method (a kind of a getter that would be named ListBuffer the result of which would be stored in `test`).

If you consistently want to make IntelliJ you want to import something, maybe try specifying the type of the object like this:

```
val test: ListBuffer = ListBuffer()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It has the same behavior with that code, sometimes it tries to import things and then other times it gives more options.

Comment: Maybe the first time he offers the one and the second the latter. It might depend on your use of IntelliJ I think there's some intelligence here. Just don't waste too much time on this problem, it's not really one ;)

Comment: yeah, I'm more just curious cause it is such a strange behavior, obviously it doesn't really matter